# NHibernate createQuery with colons from method cal

Tags: nhibernate

I get a `Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException` thrown when trying to run the following query in NHibernate.

```
IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("from <table> where 1 in (select <column>.STIntersects(geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(:longitude :latitude)', 4326)))");
```

I'm setting longitude and latitude in setQuery.

my assumption is the `::` in calling `geography::STGeomFromText...` because it's thinking it's a query parameter. Is there a way to escape the `:`?

This query works in my SQL Manager Studio.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this post for some more info: [Using SQL Server 2008 Geography types with nHibernate's CreateSQLQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238050/using-sql-server-2008-geography-types-with-nhibernates-createsqlquery/650451#650451)

Answer (score 1):

Does NHIbernate support the STIntersects method ?

What you could do, is let NHibernate execute a (native) SQL query, like this:

```
ISQLQuery query = session.CreateSQLQuery ("your sql statement goes here");
query.AddEntity (typeof(TheEntityTypeThatYouWant));

var result = query.List<TheEntityTypeThatYouWant>();
```

Comment: Good suggestion. I forgot to mention I tried that too. Those darn semi-colons!

Answer (score 0):

Just to share what I ended up doing was taking the ADO connection out of the NHibernate session, performing a SqlCommand directly and manually built my Model objects from the results. It sucks, but it works. The connection still managed by NHibernate correctly.