# combining sql server spatial and NHibernate with CreateSqlQuery

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, spatial, geography

I have not mapped geography table in sql server 2008, and I want to query it with a polygon instance in c# using nhibernate.

In the beggining I was trying to use sql server spatial directly but encountered this problem:
[Using SQL Server 2008 Geography types with nHibernate's CreateSQLQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238050/using-sql-server-2008-geography-types-with-nhibernates-createsqlquery)

My second try was this:

```
session.CreateSQLQuery("select [shape] from [table] where (:codeShape).STIntersects([shape]) = 1").SetParameter("codeShape", codeShape, NHibernateUtil.Custom(typeof(MsSql2008GeographyType)));
```

however this try also raise an exception:

```
Could not execute query [select [shape] from [table] where (?).STIntersects([shape]) = 1")] Name:codeShape - Value:POLYGON((30 40, ...))
```

and the inner exception is:

```
The specified input does not represent a valid geography instance.
```

That's despite codeShape.IsValid returns true.

When I run this query directly in sql server I get the expected result.

any ideas or solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

problem resolved. I had to reverse the points of the polygon.